# Searching Git for multiple hash's at one time

Tags: git, grep, git-log, git-grep

I just got a directive to revert a bunch of committed code.  The good news is that all commit's have a reference string in them, something like:

```
ABC-1556
ABC-1616
ABC-4818
ABC-5919
```

This commend will give me one of them, how do I modify the grep commend to find them all?

```
git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --grep='ABC-1556'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put all your reference strings into a file (say, `patterns`), and then use `xargs` to run the `git log` command for each string:

```
xargs -iPATTERN git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --grep="PATTERN" < patterns
```

If it's just a small number of patterns you could combine them on the command line like this:

```
git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit -E --grep="ABC-1556|ABC-1616|ABC-4818|ABC-5919"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had tried this, but it didn't work:

```
git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --grep='ABC-1556|ABC-1616'
```

But I discovered this did:

```
git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --grep=ABC-1556 --grep=ABC-1616
```

Problem solved!